# PostgreSQL - pg_config -bash: pg_config: command not found

Tags: bash, unix, postgresql, shell, path

I'm on a Mac building an app in Rails 3 with PostgreSQL...

PostgreSQL is working fine but in the command line I get the following error:

```
$ pg_config
-bash: pg_config: command not found
```

Anyone know how to get this setup so I can run pg_config?

Thanks

Answer (score 69, accepted):

you can install postgresql-devel to get that. in rpm based distro

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```

will work

or use

```
yum provides "*/pg_config"
```

to get the exact package

Comment: For those who find this answer, this program is now part of the package `libpq-dev`

Comment: on Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

Comment: For those who find this answer, I still found this program in `postgresql-devel` in the CentOS Updates repo with CentOS 5.5

Comment: Find it finally, thank you. I'm on CentOS and after yum provides I run: `python26 setup.py install build_ext --pg-config /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config` to run on python 2.6 / postgre 9.2

Answer (score 9):

In addition to installing `postgresql-devel` I had to modify the `PATH` environment variable. E.g. add this to your `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin"
```

Answer (score 4):

My problem was that `pg_config` was not in the PATH. So, I first needed to search for `pg_config`'s path by using

```
yum provides "*/pg_config"
```

After noting the path, I used this command to install pg gem

```
gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config
```

That installed `pg` successfully. The system was a CentOS.

Comment: Confirmed with Fedora 24:

`dnf install postgresql-devel`

`gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 3):

pg_config is a PostgreSQL util, you can get it by installing PostgreSQL.
On mac:

```sh
brew install postgresql
```

Answer (score 1):

Find where `pg_config` is located: `find / -name pg_config 2>/dev/null`
Copy the path then do: `export PATH=/usr/local/pgsql/bin:$PATH`. Make sure to use your correct copied path.

Answer (score 0):

`pg_config` comes with the development files for PostgreSQL. Go to where you got the server daemon from and look for them there.

Answer (score 0):

i have a CentOS 5.11 with postgres 9.0, and python 2.4 , python 2.6 to run openERP 6, trying to install the psycopg2 i allways get the error:

```
# python26 setup.py install --with-xslt-config=/usr/local/bin/xslt-config --with-xml2-config=/usr/local/bin/xml2-config
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: setup.py --help-commands
   or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --with-xslt-config not recognized
```

from :[how to install pg_config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293111/postgresql-pg-config-bash-pg-config-command-not-found#comment22154314_4294164)
Later i do :

```
yum provides "*/pg_config"
```

i get a list, where we can find

```
postgresql84-devel-8.4.20-1.el5_10.x86_64 : PostgreSQL development header     files
                                          : and libraries
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/pg_config
```

but if i try to install, its already installed
So i use

```
yum provides "*/pg_config"
```

later you need install the rigth vertion, for your architecture(32bit or 64bit), in my case was:

```
yum install postgresql84-devel-8.4.20-1.el5_10.x86_64
```

then update

```
yum update
```

and finally install psycopg2 with pip

pip install psycopg2