# install pg_config in CentOS 5.5 without yum

Tags: postgresql, centos

python version 2.4

## # pip install psycopg2

Getting the following error:

Downloading/unpacking psycopg2
   Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.

Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:

    python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
running egg_info

 writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
 writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
 writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
 warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

Error: pg_config executable not found.
Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
or specify the full executable path with the option:
python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /root/sources/build/psycopg2
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
[root@host sources]# which pg_config
/usr/bin/which: no pg_config in     (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/b    in:/root/bin)
```

I am unable to install pg_config as an executable

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to install `postgresql-devel` package.

Or build Postgres from source and then you'll have `pg_config` not from a package.

Answer (score 7):

For AWS linux (or RedHat for that matter) use:

```
sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answer is correct: you need to install the `-devel` package. Furthermore, I found via [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293111/postgresql-pg-config-bash-pg-config-command-not-found#comment22154314_4294164) that you then might need to manually specify where to look for `pg_config` to build `psycopg2`.

In particular, I wound up running

```
python2.7 setup.py build_ext --pg-config /usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/pg_config install
```

Note that this path will depend on your postgres version.